# Angular 8: erros in core.ts when running "ng build --prod"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I don't know what's the cause of the errors since they are in the `core.ts` file of Angular.
This is the output:

```
ERROR in @angular/core/core.ts(194,31): Error during template compile of 'NgModule
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
@angular/core/core.ts(756,18): Error during template compile of 'Component'       
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.                                 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'                                     
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called. 
@angular/core/core.ts(194,31): Error during template compile of 'NgModule'        
  Function calls are not supported in decorators.
```

my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialComponentsModule } from './material-components.module';
import { RoutingPipe } from './pipes/routing.pipe';
import { ContainerComponent } from './views/container/container.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './views/users/users.component';
import { TrackingSheetsComponent } from './views/tracking-sheets/tracking-sheets.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { GridTableComponent } from './components/grid-table/grid-table.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler } from './services/app-errors/error-handler';
import { ATTPInterceptor } from './services/http.interceptor';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material';
import { CustomErrorStateMatcher } from './utils/custom-error-state-matcher';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy, DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
import { LoaderComponent } from './components/loader/loader.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './components/modal/modal.component';
import { UserFormComponent } from './views/users/user-form/user-form.component';
import { UserSaveComponent } from './views/users/user-save/user-save.component';
import { TrackingSheetSaveComponent } from './views/tracking-sheets/tracking-sheet-save/tracking-sheet-save.component';
import { TrackingSheetFormComponent } from './views/tracking-sheets/tracking-sheet-form/tracking-sheet-form.component';
import {AttachmentSelectorComponent} from "./components/attachment-selector/attachment-selector.component";
import {SlarnAutocompleteModule} from "./components/slarn-autocomplete/slarn-autocomplete.module";
import {ImageSelectorComponent} from "./components/image-selector/image-selector.component";
import {SbcDatePickerComponent} from "./components/sbc-date-picker/sbc-date-picker.component";
import {DatepickerOverviewExample} from "./components/sbc-date-adapter/datepicker-overview-example";
import { CustomerContainerComponent } from './views/customer-area/customer-container/customer-container.component';
import { CustomerDashboardComponent } from './views/customer-area/customer-dashboard/customer-dashboard.component';
import { CustomerTrackingSheetComponent } from './views/customer-area/customer-tracking-sheet/customer-tracking-sheet.component';
import {SlickCarouselModule} from "ngx-slick-carousel";
import { LightBoxComponent } from './components/light-box/light-box.component';
import { ContactsComponent } from './views/customer-area/contacts/contacts.component';
import {NgxContentLoadingModule} from "ngx-content-loading";
import {ImplodePipe} from "./pipes/implode.pipe";
import {TruncatePipe} from "./pipes/truncate.pipe";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    RoutingPipe,
    UsersComponent,
    TrackingSheetsComponent,
    GridTableComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    ModalComponent,
    UserFormComponent,
    UserSaveComponent,
    TrackingSheetSaveComponent,
    TrackingSheetFormComponent,
    ImageSelectorComponent,
    AttachmentSelectorComponent,
    SbcDatePickerComponent,
    DatepickerOverviewExample,
    CustomerContainerComponent,
    CustomerDashboardComponent,
    CustomerTrackingSheetComponent,
    LightBoxComponent,
    ContactsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialComponentsModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    HttpClientModule,
    SlarnAutocompleteModule,
    SlickCarouselModule,
    // NgxContentLoadingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorHandler,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ATTPInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher,
      useClass: CustomErrorStateMatcher
    },
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    RoutingPipe,
    DatePipe,
    ImplodePipe,
    TruncatePipe
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LoaderComponent,
    DatepickerOverviewExample
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "second-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/second-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
              "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "second-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "second-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "second-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "second-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "second-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "second-frontend"
}
```

What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Can you also upload you angular.json file ?

Comment: @TonyNgo I have added angular.json file

Comment: I just update my answer. Check your code with mine to see if there any different

Comment: @TonyNgo ok I will check it

Answer (score 1):

Just post it here to help everyone that have same problem

Update your tsconfig.json file with either options

```
"skipTemplateCodegen": false,
"strictMetadataEmit": false
```

or

```
"skipTemplateCodegen": true,
"strictMetadataEmit": true,
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
```

Another suggest link to take a look at

https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/156#issue-207301509

Update double check my config with your to see if it work

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular8": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular8",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular8:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular8:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular8:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular8:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular8:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "angular8"
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked but I can't find index.html in the dist folder !! is this related to your answer ? although I have `<base href="./">`

Comment: You mean you cant see index.html in the final build ?

Comment: Hm. Then I think maybe releated to the tsconfig.json. Can you check the service you add in the `useClass` to see if there any syntax error like the link I send and revert tsconfig,json file again then run build to see if it work

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You should show us your app.module files and the usage of ɵmakeDecorator for a more detailed investigation, but it seems that you should check if you are using imports correctly. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/727)</strike>

EDIT:
Just moving up the solution that seems to work for the author which was provided in this post comments:

> This comment right here [github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/](http://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/)… was helpful

Comment: Just a blind guess, but since you have commented out NgxContentLoadingModule then you should remove a comma after SlickCarouselModule in NgModule imports section

Comment: @donatasj87 thats not the problem.

Comment: @Minato do you have a clue about this ? anything that could help ?

Comment: @SlimenTN from the error message, what I can guess is that `AgGridModule.withComponents([])` this type of thing is not supported, so try compiling the code without this and see if it works or the error comes out different.

Comment: @Minato I have removed `withComponents()` and kept it just like that `AgGridModule` but it didn't work.

Comment: This comment right here https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/822#issuecomment-386875167 was helpful